# Git Conundrum: rm -r and .gitignore not working

Tags: git

I just added the following line to my `.gitignore`

```
*.pyc
```

1) I then ran the command

```
git rm -r --cached *.pyc
```

but it did not work recursively and I instead got the error `fatal: pathspec 'RepoName.pyc' did not match any files`

2) Even worse, when I next tried a

```
git add .
```

All the files that are normally not added due to my `.gitignore` were staged for commit. I then removed the `*.pyc` line but this behavior continued.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Note:

When running `git status` I do not see the 'normally ignored' files as untracked files.

Answer (score 3):

Shell wildcards don't work recursively. They are expanded in the context of the current directory by the shell before Got is executed. You'll need something like

```
 ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

---

Explanation of options:

- `ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard` Show files that should be ignored.
- `-z` Use a NUL (`\0`) separator for output, to avoid issues with spaces in filenames.
- `xargs -0` Run the next command for each NUL-separated record read from `stdin`.
- `git rm --cached` Remove from the index only, not from the working tree.

Comment: or `.. | xargs git rm --cached` as the OP was trying to do.

Comment: Right; updated answer to use `git rm --cached` plus use NUL separators for robustness in case of whitespace in filenames.